# Paperclip + S3 + Nginx issue on image upload

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am using paperclip with S3 to save my users images in an amazon bucket. The working version used to save images in **s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/users/photos/000/000/1/small/photo.jpg**. When I created `Male and Female models (subclasses of User)` it started to search images in **s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/males/photos/000/000/1/small/photo.jpg** (`if the user is a male`).

Furthermore, when I try to create a new photo I got a `nginx 500 Internal Server Error` and have **no log in rails application.**

How should I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue sometime ago and it worked for me just to restart my web server. I was using Passenger in my application.

I forgot to mention that I created an interpolation with Paperclip method Interpolates, just like that:

```
#config/initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip.interpolates :class  do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.class.model_name.downcase.pluralize
end
```

Now the files url at S3 will make use of .../users/..., not .../males/... or .../females/... anymore.